# Powershell Regex new Email standards

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to validate emails with special rules. These rules include are:

- hyphens in the tld
- numbers in the tld
- subdomains, but each subdomain can not have more than 63 characters.
- Each subdomain can only accept a-zA-Z . _ - characters

I am getting stuck on the 63 character limit per subdomain. Here is the code I have so far. (https://regex101.com/r/eyskK0/1)

```
^([\w\-\.]+)@([\w\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)
```

This part controls the subdomains.

```
([\w\-\.]+)\.
```

The final . after the +) controls the end of the subdomains. There are up to 500 subdomains available.

Here are a few things I have tried out with no success. This code below accepts the <> symbols in the subdomains which aren't want we are going for. (https://regex101.com/r/tO66PE/1)

```
([\w\.]+)@((([\w\-]{1,63})\.){1,500})([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)
```

This is the test string I am working with. Once I can figure out the 63 character limit then this string will not work.

```
bob-ross_yeah.nes@111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333.444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444.125225.XN--BCK1B9A5DRE4C
```

I am aware of this code floating around the internet but the requirements are not met here.

```
^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Below is the powershell I am using:

```
$Email = "bob-ross_yeah.nes@111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333.444444444444444444444444444444<444444444444444444444444444444444.125225.XN--BCK1B9A5DRE4C"
$Regex = "([\w\.]+)@((([\w\-]{1,63})\.){1,500})([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)"
if ($Email -match $Regex) {$True} else {$false}
$Regex = "^([\w\-\.]+)@([\w\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)"
if ($Email -match $Regex) {$True} else {$false}
```

This presents an answer of true.

Regex is a beast.

Comment: What is the specific question? Do you want to limit the number of ocurrences of an element? Maybe see [quantifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1#quantifiers).

Comment: `^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]){2,63}){0,500})(\.([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))$` has potential I think

Comment: If you search, you will find a lot of opihnions, samples, etc., about this use case. Many say, it is an exercise in futility since there can/are so many variables when details with, especially when cross national boundaries are in the mix. It might be prudent to pull a list of your address and use that to `create a template for conversion`. [ConvertFrom-String: Example-based text parsing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/convertfrom-string-example-based-text-parsing/) and use that to compare data against it.

Comment: The best way to validate an email address is to send an email and check the return value. 
Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: toto (https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) this is what the tld's are based on. The subdomain is what the internals of the client are based on. 
@Daniel this looks very promising. I like how you broke down the \w and grouped the \. with the last part. So far it's passing the tests. {0,500} to {1,500} so we can see if there is at least 1 domain. I have tried to break the solution. Odd characters do break the solution. so things like, <> will do it. Which is what I am looking for.